# adding a blank row in the SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, visibility

I have groups in my ssrs report and have set visibility to false if there are no values in that group. However I want to have one blank row for that group if its empty.. is there a work around for that..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting visibility on the entire group, you could set the visibility to false on only the group detail and add an additional group header or footer to create a blank row regardless of data visibility.